# MaskedEditExtender validation issue

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a textbox for U.S phone number. For this i am using MaskedEditExtender and RegularExpressionValidator to check if user has entered the number in a correct format. Following is the code:

```
<ajax:MaskedEditExtender ID="meePhoneNumber" runat="server" Mask="999-999-9999" TargetControlID="tbComapnyPhoneNumber" MaskType="Number" ClearMaskOnLostFocus="false" AutoComplete="false" MessageValidatorTip="true" ErrorTooltipEnabled="true" />

<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revCompanyPhone" runat="server" ValidationExpression="((\(\d{3}\) ?)|(\d{3}-))?\d{3}-\d{4}( x\d{0,})?" ControlToValidate="tbComapnyPhoneNumber" ErrorMessage="Please enter a valid phone number" Display="Dynamic" />
```

Now when i save the data it validates the textbox even though it is not required field validator. When i change ClearMaskOnLostFocus to true then it saves the data even if i leave the etxtbox empty but when i change it to false it doesn't let me save.

Answer (score 1):

Force validator to consider a mask text as valid value:

```
ValidationExpression="(((\(\d{3}\) ?)|(\d{3}-))?\d{3}-\d{4}( x\d{0,})?)|(^___-___-____$)"
```